# How to place every word in a list as an entry in the dictionary

Tags: python

I have a List of multiple documents. so for example

```
List = ["today is a beautiful day","tomorrow is rainy day"]
```

today is a beautiful day is the first document

tomorrow is rainy day is the second document

What I need to do is to look up search terms, so if I look up "beautiful" I will get 0, for the first document, If I look up day, I should get 0 and 1, since both have the word day in them.  I am going to use a dictionary for this purpose. Each entry in the dictionary should have a word as the key and the word’s value as the set of documents that this word appears in. This arrangement allows me to look up a keyword in the dictionary and immediately get all the documents that it appears in, making it easy to figure out documents that might meet a search query.

This is what I have so far, I am not sure how to place every word in a list as an entry in the dictionary:

```
def searchList(documentNum):
    with open("ap_docs.txt", 'r') as myfile:
        list = [item.strip() for item in myfile.read().split('<NEW DOCUMENT>') if item]
        print(list[documentNum])




print("1-Search for documents")
print("2- Read Document")
print("3-Quit Program")
choice = input("What would you like to do ?")



if choice == '1':
    with open("ap_docs2.txt", 'r') as myfile:
        List = [item.strip() for item in myfile.read().split('<NEW DOCUMENT>') if item]
    from collections import defaultdict   

    d = defaultdict(set)

    for doc_no, doc in enumerate(List):
        for line in doc:
            for word in line.strip().split():
                d[word].update([doc_no])
    print(d['moon'])



if choice == '2':
    documentNum = int(input("What is the document number ?"))
    searchList(documentNum)


if choice == '3':
    exit()
```

In effect I am trying to make an [Inverted Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) in Python with the help of a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very clear what you want to do, and how, but you could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and set (if i understand you correctly). For example:

```
# mockup of lines read from two documents
doc_lines_1 = ["today is a beautiful day", "tomorrow is rainy day"]
doc_lines_2 = ["tomorrow is rainy day is the second document"]

# a list containing your documents
doc_list = [doc_lines_1, doc_lines_2]


from collections import defaultdict   

d = defaultdict(set)

for doc_no, doc in enumerate(doc_list):
    for line in doc:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            d[word].update([doc_no])


print(d['day'])     # {0, 1} "day" in both document 0 and 1           
print(d['rainy'])   # {0, 1} "rainy" in both document 0 and 1      
print(d['second'])  # {1}    "second" only in document 1
```

p.s.
DON'T use `list` as a variable name. You are overwriting build in `list` type.

Comment: so I am getting printed out for print(d['day'])  set(). Any word I try to print and get the number of document I am getting instead set(). why is that ?

Comment: This is printing set() and not the document number . May I know the reason ?

Comment: @Mozein Documents number are in set. Set contain only unique values, so using set ensures that you will get only one file number per word.

Comment: yes but this is not working when I try to do `print(d['day'])`  I get the output `set()` and not the number of the document this word is in.

Comment: Maybe you adapted the example with some mistake to what you have in your actual code.

Comment: please check the edit. Specifically the first if statement of choice == 1
Also you should know that These 2 documents were just examples. My document actually have many more documents, and moon is included that is why I am trying it

Comment: I am expecting to get a number out, like 3, which means it is in document 3

Answer (score 2):

Try this(not clear what actually your expected outout):

```
d = {}
for i in set(" ".join(List).split()):
    d[i] = [j for j in List if i in j]

>>>d
{'a': ['today is a beautiful day', 'tomorrow is rainy day'],
 'beautiful': ['today is a beautiful day'],
  'day': ['today is a beautiful day', 'tomorrow is rainy day'],
  ....}

>>>d['day']
['today is a beautiful day', 'tomorrow is rainy day'] # list of string cotains `day`

>>>d['beautiful']
['today is a beautiful day'] # list of string contains 'beautiful'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how it's done.

```
List1 = ["today is a beautiful day", "tomorrow is rainy day"]

content = 'beautiful'

def function(content, *args):
    return all([content in i for i in [string.split() for string in args]])

print function(content, *List1)
```

Comment: It's pretty clear that he's not going to have only doc1 and doc2, so that's not a solution.